# Problema al ignorar validación en un formulario

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Tengo un problema al ignorar un campo en un formulario cuando está oculto, ya que me lo procesa y me da error de validación. 
En el **.html** tengo algo como esto:

```
 <div th:id="'valorVariable2' + ${iterStatus.index+1}" class="col-lg-5 valor2-div"
                th:classappend="${!#lists.isEmpty(#fields.errors('valoresEntradaCom[__${iterStatus.index}__].value')) ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <br>
                <label id='myIdLabel2' class="control2-label">[[#{solicitude.new.input.value_label}]]:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control valor-reg2 writable required" readonly 
                    th:name="${solicitude.valoresEntradaCom[__${iterStatus.index}__].value}"
                    th:field="${solicitude.valoresEntradaCom[__${iterStatus.index}__].value}" 
                />
                <th:block th:replace="fragments/field_errors :: errors ('valoresEntradaCom[__${iterStatus.index}__].value')" />
            </div>
```

En la siguiente función `comboVariableChange` lo que hago es mostrar o no el div dependiendo de si el texto seleccionado es `IP` que entonces mi div se mostrará y en caso contrario no. Además de esto cuando se oculte el div añadiré la clase `ignore (addClass('ignore'))` con la idea de que no lo valide el formulario, y eliminaré la clase cuando si lo muestre `removeClass('ignore')`.

```
var comboVariableChange = function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.find('option:selected').text() == 'IP') {
        $(".valor2-div").show();
        $(".valor-reg2").removeClass('ignore');

    } else {
        $(".valor2-div").hide();
        $(".valor-reg2").addClass('ignore');
    }
};
```

En mi validar formulario tengo algo como lo siguiente:

```
  $("form[name='solicitude-create-form']").validate({
        // Specify validation rules
          ignore: ".ignore", 
        rules: {
          referencia: "required",
          diligencia: "required",
          fechaSolicitud: "required",  
          "valoresEntradaCom[]": "required",
          lastname: "required",
          email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
          },
......
```

Con la idea de que en la validación ignore aquello que tenga la clase `ignore`. 
La verdad es que no tengo mucha experiencia con javascript por lo que perfectamente podría estar cometiendo un error gordo o que directamente esta no sea la mejor manera de hacerlo.
Cualquier cosa en la que podáis ayudarme os lo agradeceré.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos!

Comment: Pero qué es lo que no funciona? está validando un elemento que no debe validar? No debieras añadir esa clase a un input en vez de un div?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta ante todo. Exactamente, lo que sucede es que me está validando el elemento que no quiero que me valide. Es posible lo que comentas, lo he probado como dices, añadiendo la clase al input pero continua validando. He modificado el código en mi pregunta ¿podría ser algo así? Es posible que haya algo incorrecto...

Comment: Comprobaste que al cambiar la opción en el select ese input tenga la clase `ignore`? Así como lo veo se la estás añadiendo a todos los input.